# same invoice no for all invoice lines

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
tbl_invoice(invno,company_name,date,total) primary key(invno)
```

`invno` is auto-increment. And another table

```
tbl_invoicelines(lineid,invno,productname,qty,unitprice,amount).
primary key(lineid,invno)
```

`lineno` is auto-increment

How should I give my `MySql insert` statement so that I get a particular `invno` for an invoice even if there are multiple invoice lines?
I am really new to programming.Please help.

Comment: INSERT is for adding records, but you are asking for getting records so I assume you mean a SELECT statement?

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you are attempting to obtain, In what table you want to insert a row?

Comment: If you tell us what programming language you use and show us the current code, someone could write a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use multiple statements one after the other.

Step 1:
First execute a statement `"insert into tbl_invoice ..."` to insert the row into the invoice table. In this insert, do not specify a value for invno. One will be chosen automatically by the database.

Step 2:
Then execute the following statement: `"select LAST_INSERT_ID();"`. This will give you the ID that was chosen by the database as the invno. Store the ID that the SQL statement returns into a local variable.

Step 3: Then you can execute multiple insert statements for the tbl_invoicelines table, building the SQL string by using the variable you obtained at step 2.

Use a transaction around all three steps so that if one of the steps fails, you can rollback and undo all three of them.

Comment: I get this exception "Field 'invno' doesnt have a default value"

Comment: At what step? At the first or third step?

Comment: Step 3. `INSERT INTO tbl_invoiceline (pname,qty,unitprice,amount) values..`

Comment: I have extended the answer for clarification. You must remember the result of step 2 into a local variable and then use that local variable to construct the insert statements in step 3, using the result of step 2 as input for the invno column in step 3.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank u so much.